# Showing entire X Axis Ticks in Graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to have the tick labels of my Graph displayed fully, but I'm not getting the desired result, despite my efforts.

If I merely use `autofmt_xdate()`, the dates are correctly shown, but not for every data point plotted; however, if I force my x tick labels to be displayed by passing x by `datetime` objects to `xtick()`, It only seems to display the year.

```
    fig1 = plt.figure(1)
    # x is a list of datetime objects
    plt.title('Portfolio Instruments')
    plt.subplot(111)
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.xticks(fontsize='small')
    plt.yticks([i * 5 for i in range(0, 15)])
    fig1.autofmt_xdate()
    plt.show()
```

Graph passing x to `plt.xticks()`:
[image: With passed X labels]

Graph without passing x to `plt.xticks()`
[image: Without passed X labels]

Where's my mistake? I can't find it.

**Question**
How do I plot all of my data points of x and format it to show the entire datetime object I'm passing the graph using `autofmt_xdate()`?

I have a list of datetime objects which I want to pass as the x values of my plot.

Comment: If you know the number of datapoints beforehand, or if there will always be the same amount of data you can set the xticks to be equal to a certain number. If there was a simpler example which gave you the same problem then it would be easier to give a more specific answer.

Comment: But that's what I'm doing already, afaik, when I pass list `x` to `xticks()` or not? I have a known number of data points.

Comment: So what I thought was that `autofmt_xdate` sees the datetime objects passed to `xticks()` and converts them, just like it did before. This is not the case. The only difference is that I'm forcing the graph to show all x tick labels on the x axis.

Comment: I've simplified the code above.

Comment: See my answer here for another option: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39714724/pandas-plot-x-axis-tick-frequency-how-can-i-show-more-ticks/48401584#48401584 I wasn't sure if adding it here was o.k. due to cross-posting. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the dates you want ticks at to `xticks`, and then set the major formatter for the x axis, using `plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter`:

You can then use the [`DateFormatter` from `matplotlib.dates`](http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter), and use a [`strftime`](http://strftime.org/) format string to get the format in your question:

```
import matplotlib.dates as dates
fig1 = plt.figure(1)
# x is a list of datetime objects
plt.title('Portfolio Instruments')
plt.subplot(111)
plt.plot(x, y)

plt.xticks(x,fontsize='small') 
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%b %d %Y'))

plt.yticks([i * 5 for i in range(0, 15)])

fig1.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Note: I created the data for the above plot using the code below, so `x` is just a list of `datetime` objects for each weekday in a month (i.e. without weekends).

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime,timedelta

start = datetime(2016, 1, 1)
end = datetime(2016, 2, 1)
delta = timedelta(days=1)
d = start
weekend = set([5, 6])

x = []
while d <= end:
    if d.weekday() not in weekend:
        x.append(d)
    d += delta

y = np.random.rand(len(x))*70
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure I had a similar problem, and the way I solved it was to use the following code:

```
def formatFig():
    date_formatter = DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S') #change the format here to whatever you like
    plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_formatter)
    max_xticks = 10      # sets the number of x ticks shown. Change this to number of data points you have
    xloc = plt.MaxNLocator(max_xticks)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(xloc)

def makeFig():
    plt.plot(xList,yList,color='blue')    
    formatFig()

makeFig()
plt.show(block=True)
```

It is a pretty simple example but you should be able to transfer the `formatfig()` part to use in your code.