# How to change the x-axis tick frequency of pandas.plot

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, time-series

I am plotting time series using pandas .plot() and want to see every month shown as an x-tick.

Here is the dataset structure
[image: data set]

Here is the result of the .plot()

[image]

I was trying to use examples from other posts and matplotlib [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/date_demo2.html) and do something like

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(
   dates.MonthLocator(revenue_pivot.index, bymonthday=1,interval=1))
```

But that removed all the ticks :(

I also tried to pass `xticks = df.index`, but it has not changed anything.

What would be the rigth way to show more ticks on x-axis?

Comment: Are you parsing the dates as datetimes?

Comment: @DemetriP thanks. looks like it was at least a part of the problem. now after using ax.xaxis.set_major_locator I do see ticks... The only problem is now I only see one tick per year. 
I clearly using MonthLocator wrong.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

No need to pass any args to `MonthLocator`. Make sure to use `x_compat` in the `df.plot()` call per @Rotkiv's answer.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100,2), index=pd.date_range('1-1-2018', periods=100))
ax = df.plot(x_compat=True)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())
plt.show()
```

- formatted x-axis with `set_major_locator`

[image]

- unformatted x-axis

[image]

Answer (score 12):

You could also format the x-axis ticks and labels of a pandas `DateTimeIndex` "manually" using the attributes of a pandas `Timestamp` object.

I found that much easier than using locators from `matplotlib.dates` which work on other datetime formats than pandas (if I am not mistaken) and thus sometimes show an odd behaviour if dates are not converted accordingly.

Here's a generic example that shows the first day of each month as a label based on attributes of pandas `Timestamp` objects:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# data
dim = 8760
idx = pd.date_range('1/1/2000 00:00:00', freq='h', periods=dim)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(dim, 2), index=idx)

# select tick positions based on timestamp attribute logic. see:
# https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Timestamp.html
positions = [p for p in df.index
             if p.hour == 0
             and p.is_month_start
             and p.month in range(1, 13, 1)]
# for date formatting, see:
# https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior
labels = [l.strftime('%m-%d') for l in positions]

# plot with adjusted labels
ax = df.plot(kind='line', grid=True)
ax.set_xlabel('Time (h)')
ax.set_ylabel('Foo (Bar)')
ax.set_xticks(positions)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)

plt.show()
```

yields:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

The right way to do that described [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#suppressing-tick-resolution-adjustment)
Using the x_compat parameter, it is possible to suppress automatic tick resolution adjustment

`df.A.plot(x_compat=True)`

Comment: Does not work for me. Python 3.6, pandas 0.19.2. Any idea why?

Comment: me neither, python 3.6 and pandas 0.22

Comment: @seanysull It should be quite simple to fix with the exact information. Unfortunately, this question has no [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so it's difficult to tell whether your dataframe etc is set up the same as OPs (as OP answered themselves they may have done something "behind the scenes" that fixed the problem). I personally would have asked another question, linking to this one explaining why this didn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just show more ticks, you can also dive deep into the structure of [pd.plotting._converter](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.24.1/pandas/plotting/_converter.py):

```
dai = ax.xaxis.minor.formatter.plot_obj.date_axis_info
dai['fmt'][dai['fmt'] == b''] = b'%b'
```

After plotting, the `formatter` is a `TimeSeries_DateFormatter` and `_set_default_format` has been called, so `self.plot_obj.date_axis_info is not None`. You can now manipulate the structured array `.date_axis_info` to be to your liking, namely contain less `b''` and more `b'%b'`

Answer (score 0):

Remove tick labels:

```py
ax = df.plot(x='date', y=['count'])
every_nth = 10
for n, label in enumerate(ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()):
  if n % every_nth != 0:
    label.set_visible(False)
```

Lower `every_nth` to include more labels, raise to keep fewer.