# matplotlib xticks outputs wrong array

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, location, xticks

I am trying to plot a time series, which looks like this

```
ts
2020-01-01 00:00:00    1300.0
2020-01-01 01:00:00    1300.0
2020-01-01 02:00:00    1300.0
2020-01-01 03:00:00    1300.0
2020-01-01 04:00:00    1300.0
                        ...  
2020-12-31 19:00:00    1300.0
2020-12-31 20:00:00    1300.0
2020-12-31 21:00:00    1300.0
2020-12-31 22:00:00    1300.0
2020-12-31 23:00:00    1300.0
Freq: H, Name: 1, Length: 8784, dtype: float64
```

And I plot it via: `ts.plot(label=label, linestyle='--', color='k', alpha=0.75, zorder=2)`

If the time series `ts` starts from `2020-01-01` to `2020-12-31`, I get following when I call `plt.xticks()[0]`:

```
array([438288, 439032, 439728, 440472, 441192, 441936, 442656, 443400,
       444144, 444864, 445608, 446328, 447071], dtype=int64)
```

which is fine since the first element of that array actually shows the right position of the first xtick. However when I expand the time series object from `2019-01-01` to `2020-12-31`, so over 2 years, when I call the `plt.xticks()[0]`, I get following:

```
array([429528, 431688, 433872, 436080, 438288, 440472, 442656, 444864,
       447071], dtype=int64)
```

**I don't understand why now I am getting less values as xticks. So for 12 months I am getting 13 locations for xticks. But for 24 months I was expecting to get 25 locations. Instead I got only 9. How would I get all of these 25 locations?**

This is the whole script:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,4))
ts.plot(label=label, linestyle='--', color='k', alpha=0.75, zorder=2)
locs, labels = plt.xticks()
```

Comment: What's the scale difference? I bet the second plot has ticks every 3 months. To get `25` ticks, try [MonthLocator](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.MonthLocator).

Comment: you are correct. @QuangHoang however when I use `ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())` I get 575 ticks as xticks.

Comment: This question is similar to this one: [pandas .plot() x-axis tick frequency — how can I show more ticks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39714724/pandas-plot-x-axis-tick-frequency-how-can-i-show-more-ticks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matplotlib automatically selects an appropriate number of ticks and tick labels so that the x-axis does not become unreadable. You can override the default behavior by using tick locators and formatters from the [`matplotlib.dates`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib-dates) module.

But note that you are plotting the time series with the [pandas plot method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html#basic-plotting-plot) which is a wrapper around `plt.plot`. Pandas uses [custom tick formatters for time series plots](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html#custom-formatters-for-timeseries-plots) that produce nicely-formatted tick labels. By doing so, it uses x-axis units for dates that are different from the [matplotlib date units](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib-date-format), which explains why you get what looks like a random number of ticks when you try using the `MonthLocator`.

To make the pandas plot compatible with `matplotlib.dates` tick locators, you need to add the [undocumented](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) [`x_compat=True`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html#suppressing-tick-resolution-adjustment) argument. Unfortunately, this also removes the pandas custom tick label formatters. So here is an example of how to use a matplotlib date tick locator with a pandas plot and get a similar tick format (minor ticks not included):

```
import pandas as pd                # v 1.1.3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    # v 3.3.2
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

# Create sample time series stored in a dataframe
ts = pd.DataFrame(data=dict(constant=1),
                  index=pd.date_range('2019-01-01', '2020-12-31', freq='H'))

# Create pandas plot
ax = ts.plot(figsize=(10,4), x_compat=True)
ax.set_xlim(min(ts.index), max(ts.index))

# Select and format x ticks
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())
ticks = pd.to_datetime(ax.get_xticks(), unit='d') # timestamps of x ticks
labels = [timestamp.strftime('%b\n%Y') if timestamp.year != ticks[idx-1].year
          else timestamp.strftime('%b') for idx, timestamp in enumerate(ticks)]
plt.xticks(ticks, labels, rotation=0, ha='center');
```

[image: pandas_time_series]